# EXT - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of null

Tags: javascript, c#, extjs

I am trying to load a aspx page with listener on Button click:

```
            <ext:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" >
                <Listeners>
                    <Click  Handler="#{WndwToExcel}.load('\\Pages\\WebForm1.aspx');" />
                </Listeners>
            </ext:Button>
```

But when I click the button I receive this javascript error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of null

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That is because at that time `#{WndwToExcel}` doesn't exist yet

Comment: but this button is defined in this window(WndwToExcel)